# Support Vector Machines

Tags: python, classification, svm, machine-learning-model

I have ASCII data which converted from raster data in ArcGIS. I would like to use Support Vector Machine  (SVM) algorithm to create a flood prediction map. My question is that can I use ASCII file with SVM algorithm in python or how can I create an appropriate file from raster data by using ArcGIS or another method for use it in Python?